# asp.net MVC Active account

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a user account management application and I have an actionlink Activate and deactivate account but I don't find how to active each user account such as every user have an id_user and user_name and a boolean variable active. Help please!!

Comment: You're gunna have to be more clear on your question because I have no idea

Comment: how to active an account user in user account management application so that how make an public Action Result Activer(id) and i have a boolean var:Active

Answer (score 0):

Please use Identity in your application and as well as use EmailConfirmation for this purpose. if  user emailconfirmation is true it's mean his/her account is active or EmailConfirmation is false then it's mean his/her account is not active yet. for futher information please visit https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-identity-in-simple-ways-using-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: thanks; but i need that the administration activate the account of user via a button or an actionlink

Comment: you can call the method which update the EmailConfirmation column angaist UserID. and if you want code then let me know i will provide you code